# Update on Devise regex for Email validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm currently using **Devise regex**:

> `/\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/`

Which is simple and sort. But, it doesn't filter email like *`example@example..com`*.

An alternative to that is **URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP**:

> `` /\A[a-zA-Z0-9.!\#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*\z/ ``

Which will filter valid domains like *`hans@über.com`*.

I'm not good at regex, **but is there something better or how an I add a double dot validation in the first one with Devise.**

Comment: Use `/\A[^@\s]+@[^@.\s]+(?:\.[^@.\s]+)+\z/` or `/\A[^@\s]+@[^@.\s]+(?:\.[^@.\s]+)*\z/`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you explain a bit that regex? What are the differences?

Comment: A dot makes the difference. `[^@.\s]+(?:\.[^@.\s]+)+` matches any 1+ chars other than `@`, whitespace and `.` and then any 1 or more occurrences of a dot and then again any 1+ chars other than `@`, whitespace and `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refactor your regex as

```
/\A[^@\s]+@[^@.\s]+(?:\.[^@.\s]+)*\z/ # If you want to allow name@domain
/\A[^@\s]+@[^@.\s]+(?:\.[^@.\s]+)+\z/ # If you want to require at least one dot after @
```

Here,

- `\A` - start of string
- `[^@\s]+` - a negated character class that matches 1 or more characters other than `@` and whitespace
- `@`  - a `@` char
- `[^@.\s]+` - 1 or more characters other than `@`, `.` and whitespace
- `(?:\.[^@.\s]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences (or 1 or more if `+` is used at the end) of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[^@.\s]+` - 1 or more characters other than `@`, `.` and whitespace
- `\z` - end of string.

See [regex #1 demo](https://rubular.com/r/e0t8qalBjhOHKW)  and [regex #2 demo](https://rubular.com/r/bGp8Rs2sG7askt).

Comment: Can you help me with one more change? How can I not match emails like: me.@domain.com or
.me@domain.com. I tried to add condition sometinhg like +[\A.], but I need negative of that.

Comment: @codemonkey The same logic, `\A[^@.\s]+(?:\.[^@.\s]+)*@[^@.\s]+(?:\.[^@.\s]+)+\z`